# When you want to learn 'A', but before you learn 'A' you need to learn 'B', and to learn 'B' you have to learn 'C', etc

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a term or expression for this besides prerequisite?  The main idea to convey is that the topic is spiraling out of control.

Comment: "***preliminary***"? - *preceding or done in preparation for something fuller or more important*.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example of how you would use the phrase or expression.

Comment: @Xai_Phon - Welcome to the community!

Comment: @Xai_Phon - In software development, the humorous term "**yak shaving**" 
 describes precisely this situation.  You start out aiming to do A, but then you realise you must do B first.  But B requires C, which requires D, etc, *ad infinitum*.  In the end, you never end up achieving A because of the **infinite regression of dependencies**.  I've written a more complete answer below.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphonaptera_(poem) : "Great fleas have little fleas upon their backs to bite 'em, / And little fleas have lesser fleas, and so *ad infinitum*."

Comment: @rajah9 - Exactly!!  And there's also "turtles all the way down", which I had wanted to add but decided not to, in order to keep the answer simple.  See: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Turtles_all_the_way_down.

Comment: It reminds me of the song "There is a hole in my bucket", but that one is circular.

Comment: Depending on what you're asking, a person trying to learn A before addressing prerequisites B, C, etc, could be said to be ["out of their depth"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out_of_one%27s_depth) - meaning that they're attacking a topic several levels more advanced than they have competency to execute.

Comment: You didn't ask for a phrase, so I won't post one as an answer, but we sometimes say 'learning to walk before you can run'

Comment: I don't know if the term is in general use or what, but I've used the term "but firsts" (as in "... *but first* you need to ...") to describe the items in that kind of chain. "I'm working on doing A, however I'm still stuck working on the 'but firsts'"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word for a set of small side tasks that must happen before the primary tasks can continue](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508194/word-for-a-set-of-small-side-tasks-that-must-happen-before-the-primary-tasks-can)

Comment: [Fixing a light bulb?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbSehcT19u0)

Comment: @user170231 - Oh, that "fixing a light bulb" clip was so perfect! :)

Answer (score 39):

In the software development world, there is a humorous term called **"yak shaving"** that describes a very similar situation of **cascading dependencies.**

As noted on https://americanexpress.io/yak-shaving/:

> "Yak shaving refers to a task, that leads you to perform another
>   related task and so on, and so on — all distracting you from your
>   original goal.

In other words, we want to start some task, but there is something that precedes that one, and so on, *ad infinitum*.

The internet is full of examples of yak shaving.  One thoughtful example that I like is at https://blog.gruntwork.io/introducing-the-yak-shaving-series-247e7f20f81, where the author likens software development to a fractal:

> ".... when you actually start doing the project, you begin to zoom in, and
>   realize there is quite a bit of detail hiding in every corner. And
>   each of those details seems to have more details attached to it, and
>   each of those has more, and so on."

Bringing this back to your example - where subject A has a prerequisite of B, which in turn has a prerequisite of C, etc - I would refer to it as **an infinite regression of dependencies** ... or simply as **yak shaving** if you want the humorous term. :)

Comment: For those who never shaved a yak, why exactly this activity was chosen as a metaphor?

Comment: @svavil -  Here's a lovely reference from 11 Feb 2000 - almost exactly 20 years ago!!! - about the origins of the term "yak shaving".  http://projects.csail.mit.edu/gsb/old-archive/gsb-archive/gsb2000-02-11.html.  It's a wonderful read!

Comment: I understand what the activity includes, but I cannot grasp a connection to actual living beasts. Why not "sheep shaving" or "goat shaving"?

Comment: @svavil - I came across the term myself more than a decade ago, when I was the CEO of a tech company.  I was complaining to a technical friend about the fact that I could never complete the key objective (e.g. "rebuild the platform") because there was always a never-ending set of jobs that had to be done first.  "Oh, that just means you are yak shaving!!", he said with a laugh.  And on that day I learned this very important, very technical term!

Comment: @svavil - Here's a link to someone who's tackled the problem that there is no good etymology for the term: https://www.alexandrasamuel.com/toolbox/yak-shaving-etymology.  In short, you'll find that there is NO really good reason for it being a yak rather than a sheep, a goat, an elephant or a koala.  It's simply that someone used the term ... and it caught on because the situation it describes is so well understood by all of us.

Comment: @svavil: probably because "yak" is more obscure, and so more funny. "I thought svavil was supposed to be recalibrating the main gun on the scout ship, why is he shaving a yak? And where did he get one?" "Oh man, it's a long story."

Comment: https://www.yourdictionary.com/yak-shaving explains why it's a yak.

Comment: That's what I was going to point out @shoover but you beat me to it. :-) I'm a developer and we use the term Yak Shaving. I've always thought it came from Ren & Stimpy since that's the only place I had previously seen a reference to shaving a yak.

Answer (score 19):

I've worked at a number of software development companies where it would be called:

> going down a rabbit hole

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+down+the+rabbit+hole

> To enter into a situation or begin a process or journey that is particularly strange, problematic, difficult, complex, or chaotic, **especially one that becomes increasingly so as it develops or unfolds**. (An allusion to Alice's Adventures in Wonderland by Lewis Carroll.)

(Emphasis mine)

Additionally, you might describe a specific task as a rabbit hole if you're likely to find those characteristics once you start working on it...

Comment: I first thought of this. Probably only used in Britain (and Commonwealth? ).

Comment: Not just software. People would understand "going down the rabbit hole of planning regulations" or "... inheritance tax planning" or " ... flat earther conspiracy theories"

Comment: @nigel222 Very common in AmE as well.

Comment: @nigel222 "Going down a rabbit hole" is colloquial in American English as well.

Answer (score 14):

[**Dependency hell**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) refers especially to software with conflicting dependencies, but can be used somewhat more broadly to refer to pain from prerequisites.

[**Scope creep**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scope_creep) mostly refers to new requirements being added, broadening a project's scope, but might sometimes also be applied to dependencies causing things to [spiral out of control](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/58/messages/1787.html).

Comment: Yes, "dependency hell" is such a great term!   Also, empirically, it's interesting to consider the extent to which "scope creep" is actual scope creep or unidentified dependencies.  In my own career I've seen vast amounts of scope creep but - after thinking about your answer - I realise that much of it's not genuine scope creep but a failure to consider all the related projects that need to be done to achieve the scope. 
 Good answer!

Answer (score 6):

There is a logical expression, which, though not exactly what you are asking, could reasonably be applied to it.  I mean the idea of **infinite regress**

Google.com offers this explanation.

> An infinite regress arises when we ask what are the justifications for the reasons themselves. If the reasons count as knowledge, they must themselves be justified with reasons for the reasons, and so on, ad infinitum. The problem of the infinite regress was a critical argument of the Skeptics in ancient philosophy.

Merriam Webster offers the following;

> an endless chain of reasoning leading backward by interpolating a third entity between any two entities.

The earliest such chain of reasoning  occurs in Plato, or, rather, occurs in Aristotle’s critique of Plato’s *theory of forms*.  Plato claimed that to explain the properties, like *just*, or *beautiful*, you had to understand that such qualities are reflections of real entities, *JUSTICE* and *BEAUTY*.  Aristotle, in his *Nichomachean Ethics* points out that if this were true, Then in order to understand, for example *BEAUTY*, we must have to understand a **third** entity (say **BEAUTY** and so on *ad infinity*.  This type of chain of philosophical questions is what has come to be known as *infinite regress*.  The argument that points it out has come to be known as the *third man argument.*

Children subject us to it. when they realise that to every answer you give, they can keep saying “*why*”.

Your question involves a ***regress of questions***, whether actually infinite or not.

Answer (score 6):

I call that a *chain of prerequisites,* and it applies to more than learning.

Comment: What's to expand?  If you're renovating a kitchen, you spackle, then you paint, then you install new cabinets, and so on and so on.  If you're baking a cake ... well, you get the idea.  Applying this phrase to anything else is just too obvious to be explained.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is actually called a **stack overflow** in computer science: A [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) is a LIFO data structure (last in, first out) designated to manage tasks. When too many tasks come in before they can be handled, all memory available for the stack is full. And bad things happen.

Comment: No matter how many prerequisites you have IRL, I doubt your going to run out of room to track them.  But you CAN have so many that it's going to take you a long time to get through them.